# Cursor with where null or value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cursor

I have a cursor or two rather because I can't figure out how to do this any other way.
 The problem is that `parentid` can be null in the database.   So I am testing if `@parentid  is not null` then if it is I'm running one cursor `where parentid = @parentid` and then I have another one where parent id is null.  (below)

```
declare findParent_c cursor for
        select ID , page
        from   dPageHierarchy
        where  profileid =  @profileId
        and parentid is null;
open findParent_c;
fetch findParent_c into @FindParentId, @ElementCheck;
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

     -- Do stuff here.  

fetch findParent_c into @FindParentId, @ElementCheck;
end
close findParent_c;
deallocate findParent_c;
```

Does anyone have a way around this?  I hate having double the code in the script.

Comment: Have you tried using a CASE statement in your query?

Comment: How would you add a case in a while clause to handle a posible null?

Comment: edit had my parentid and profileid mixed up in the discription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
declare findParent_c cursor for
select ID , page
from   dPageHierarchy
where  profileid =  @profileId
and ( (parentid = @parentid) or (parentid is null and @parentid is null) );
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: this cursor checks if `@parentid` is set. if it is, it selects `parentid = @parentid` if not, it selects `parentid is null and profileid = @profileid`.

```
declare findParent_c cursor for
        select ID , page
        from   dPageHierarchy
        where  (     profileid =  @profileId
                 and parentid is null 
                 and @parentid is null )
           or  (     @parentid is not null
                 and parentid = @parentid );
open findParent_c;
```

Comment: ok but if @parentid is set will that return all the null parentid as well?

Comment: I just tested it it does.

Comment: what exactly should be returned in which case?

Comment: @parentid = 123  (all the rows with parent id 123)  @parentid=null all the rows with parentid = null

Comment: what about `@profileid`? according to your question it seems it should be ignored when `@parentid` is set and used when `@parentid is null`